# Update site containing only one Eclipse helios milestone release, i.e 3.6.2, not 3.6.1/3.6.0

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.6, helios, p2, update-site

I'm trying to create an internal corporate mirror of the Helios Milestone repository `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios`, but this update site contans three releases, corresponding to (I assume) 3.6.2, 3.6.1 and 3.6.0

Is there an update site that only contains release 3.6.2? Saw that there was an indigo update site `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/201202240900`, thought there might be something similar, but google doesnt know and I got tired of trying different date/time combinations :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, found it. [This post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/204151/660325/#msg_660325) solved it.

Quote from post:

> The repository XML (available as the one and only file that you get by appending /compositeContent.jar to the URL), looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
[...]
<children size='4'>
  <child location='http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/helios/'/>
  <child location='201006230900'/>
  <child location='201009240900'/>
  <child location='201102250900'/>
</children>
```

> The thing to pay attention to are the child elements. They are relative to the composite URL which means that the smaller and coherent SR2 repository can be found at:
>   http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/201102250900
>   The same apply to http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6